# Confusing Javascript Nested Array from Facebook Graph API

Tags: javascript, arrays, facebook-graph-api, multidimensional-array, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hello_I’ve been stuck on a problem with my Javascript Array for over a week now, I just don’t know how to get it to work.

I’m querying Facebook’s Graph API in order to retrieve an array of ID numbers (these are IDs of people who have sent an app request to the currently logged in player). The tricky thing about this array is that it’s a sort of nested array, this is what I’m working with:

I’m querying the Graph API with this query:
`'me/apprequests?fields=from,id'`

This returns a response which contains details on the currently logged in player, details on the sender(s) of the app invites, and details on the app itself.

What I need are the IDs of the senders, so to drill down and isolate these pieces of data I specify what I want from the query’s response by defining it like this: `response.data[0].from.id;`

Since the number is `[0]` this will return the ID of the first sender. 
If I write `response.data[1].from.id;` it will give me the ID of the second sender, and so on.

My problem is that I don’t know how to write this array so that it will handle arrays of any size (sometimes there will be no IDs in the array, and sometimes there may be dozens).

Currently I’m testing this with an account that has received 3 app invites from 3 different people, so the array is 3 objects long. I’m able to get these 3 IDs by using this code:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');

     FB.api('me/apprequests?fields=from,id', function(response) {

     if (response.error) {
       console.log('Error - ' + response.error.message);
     }
     else {
    var requestid = [];
    requestid[0] = response.data[0].from.id;
    requestid[1] = response.data[1].from.id;
    requestid[2] = response.data[2].from.id;

    console.log(requestid);
// AJAX to send Array to PHP file for database insert goes here.
```

This will show the 3 different IDs of the 3 senders in the console. I can also get the same result using this code:

```
var requestid = [response.data[0].from.id, response.data[1].from.id, response.data[2].from.id];
```

They both return this result in the console:

`Array [ "182375352527", "41142382445744", "10114293842343" ]`

My question is, how can I change this code so that it will handle both a situation where there are no sender IDs and also a situation where there are multiple IDs.

Right now my code is working only because I'm defining the space for 3 IDs, I've tried defining space for more (for example `response.data[3].from.id`) but as there is no 4th ID number to retrieve this doesn't work and instead stops anything from being returned in the array.

Any advice on how to solve this problem would be really appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Okay, so `response.data` is an Array with an unknown number of elements?

Comment: Hi @DannyDelott thanks for your comment, when I define it as ``response.data`` it returns an array inside an array in the console like so: ``Array [ Array[3] ]`` when I click into the array, each of the 3 objects contains subheadings, the subheading I want to access is ``from``, when I click on that it displays the ID I need, I can get this ID directly in the console by using ``respone.data[0].from.id``. My problem is that the size of the array completely depends on how many invites the current user happens to have, I'm not sure how to write this to automatically handle varying size of arrays.

Comment: Gotcha, okay take a look at my answer below. Is that more along the lines of what you're going for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in a for loop. Something like:

```
var requestid = [];

for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++){
  requestid.push(response.data[i].from.id);
}
```

This will populate your `requestid` array with the number of data elements given in the response.

Comment: This works, thank you! Now I just need to work out how to insert this using PDO. :)